# jquery comparing json string with value

Tags: jquery, json, compare

I am working on a question and answer comparison example where i am trying to compare question string with json data. Questions and answers will be pulled as json data. Could you please help me guiding fix for comparison problem.

[My code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/VxfTe/5/)

```
<label for="What_is_planning">What is planning</label>
<br>
<label for="What_is_implementing">What is implementing</label>
<br>
<div class="result"></div>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('label').mouseover(function () {
        var helpString = this.firstChild.nodeValue.replace(':', '').trim();

        var answerString = "<br>No Answer";
        $(".result").html(" <hr><b>Guest: </b>" + helpString);
        $(".result").append(" <div><b>AskGFS: </b>" + answerString);
        console.log(helpString);
    });

    var QandAData = '{"gfsdata":[{"question":"what is planning","answer":"This is a important part of life"},' +
        '{"question":"what is implementing","answer":"this is followed by planning"}]}';

    //Comparing answers
    for (var i = 0; i < QandAData.length; i++) {
        if (QandAData[i].gfsdata.question == 'what is planning') {
            answerString = QandAData[i].gfsdata.answer;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the data in answer string your getting !!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Comment: FYI, there is no reason to use JSON here. You could just use an object literal and save the parsing step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('label').mouseover(function () {
        var helpString = this.firstChild.nodeValue.replace(':', '').trim();
        var answerString = "<br>No Answer";
        var QandAData = {
            "gfsdata": [{
                "question": "What is planning",
                "answer": "This is a important part of life"
            }, {
                "question": "What is implementing",
                "answer": "This is followed by planning"
            }]
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < QandAData.gfsdata.length; i++) {
            if (QandAData.gfsdata[i].question == helpString) {
                answerString = QandAData.gfsdata[i].answer;
            }
        }
        $(".result").html(" <hr><b>Guest: </b>" + helpString+" <div><b>AskGFS: </b>" + answerString);
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/VxfTe/7/)